# How to get current session locale?

Tags: java, spring, session

```
@Autowired
private SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver;

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // clean previous failed access
    authorizationServiceConfig.cleanUserFailedAccess();

    // set the session locale
    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, authorizationServiceConfig.getUserLocale());

    //redirect login..
    handle(request, response, authentication);

}
```

I need to get the SessionLocaleResolver locale value that i set before in the Authentication service. But i dont have the request here :(

```
public String getMessage(String key) {
    String answer;

    if (key == null) {
        return "";
    }
    try {
        answer = getMessageSourceAccessor().getMessage(key, "here i need the Session locale");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        answer = key;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want if to get the current request in a method that has no pointer to it, `RequestContextHolder` is you friend. As it is a common requirement, spring stores an object in a thread local variable, and gives access to it via static methods of this class :

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                                 .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

Of course if works that way in servlet application and not in portlet ones - you would have to use `PortletRequestAttributes` and finaly get a `PortletRequest`

Comment: How can you assume usage of Spring WebFlow?

Comment: `RequestContextHolder` is automatically enabled by `DispatcherServlet`. If `DispatcherServlet` is not used, it is enough to register a `RequestContextListener` in the ServletContext. It has no dependance on Spring WebFlow

Comment: aaah you are right. I knew of org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContextHolder.. Apparently there's a org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder